# Placement of dots between section and subsection numbers with Gandhari Unicode font

Tags: fonts, ligatures

I have been asked to use the [Gandhari Unicode font](https://github.com/gandhariunicode/gandhari_unicode_font) for a paper, but I get weird formatting of the dots pertaining to the numbers of sections, subsections etc.:

[image: sample output]

Particularly 1.4 looks ugly, with the dot right under the 4. My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Gandhari Unicode}

\begin{document}

\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsubsection}
\subsection{Testsubsection}
\subsection{Testsubsection}
\subsection{Testsubsection}

\end{document}
```

I suppose this is a font issue, and I should talk with the font developer. Or, is there some easy way to tell LaTeX to not apply ligatures on numbers, or whatever it is that is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Hack it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{gu}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  Path=./,
  UprightFont=*r,
  BoldFont=*b,
  ItalicFont=*i,
  BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\/.\/\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{Testsection}
\subsection{Testsubsection}
\subsection{Testsubsection}
\subsection{Testsubsection}
\subsection{Testsubsection}

\end{document}
```

I didn't install the font in the system, so I had to use the direct call to the .ttf files.

[image]